# Global vs Local variables when making calls to an API

Tags: javascript, json, api

What I am currently trying to do is create a script which takes an address and returns a map with a pinned address. I am trying to call the google geocode API and then convert the lat and lng into a returned location

What I believe I am struggling with is how to create a global variable of an API object.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 id="text-center">Enter Location: </h2>
  <form id="location-form">
    <input type="text" id="location-input" class="form-control form-control-lg">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div class="card-block" id="formatted-address"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
  <div class="card-block" id="address-components"></div>
<div class="card-block" id="geometry"></div>
```

```
<script>
// Call Geocode
//geocode();

// Get location form
var locationForm = document.getElementById('location-form');

// Listen for submit
locationForm.addEventListener('submit', geocode);

function geocode(e){
  // Prevent actual submit
  e.preventDefault();

  var location = document.getElementById('location-input').value;

  axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
    params:{
      address:location,
      key:'secret'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response){
    // Log full response
    console.log(response);

    var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    // Formatted Address
    var formattedAddress = response.data.results[0].formatted_address;
    var formattedAddressOutput = `
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">${formattedAddress}</li>
      </ul>
    `;

    // New map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

    // Address Components
    var addressComponents = response.data.results[0].address_components;
    var addressComponentsOutput = '<ul class="list-group">';
    for(var i = 0;i < addressComponents.length;i++){
      addressComponentsOutput += `
        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>${addressComponents[i].types[0]}</strong>: ${addressComponents[i].long_name}</li>
      `;
    }
    addressComponentsOutput += '</ul>';

    // Geometry
    var geometryOutput = `
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Latitude</strong>: ${lat}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Longitude</strong>: ${lng}</li>
      </ul>
    `;

    // Output to app
    document.getElementById('formatted-address').innerHTML = formattedAddressOutput;
    document.getElementById('address-components').innerHTML = addressComponentsOutput;
    document.getElementById('geometry').innerHTML = geometryOutput;
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(errorGeocode);
  });
}

  function initMap(){
  // Map options
  var options = {
    zoom:8,
    center:{lat:lat,lng:lng}
  }
 </script>
```

I continue to catch the errorGeocode console log.

Comment: what error are you getting?  im guessing it has to do with your `options` trying to reference `lat` and `lng` that don't exist in the scope outside of the function above.  that and you left off a `}` at the end to close out `initMap() { ... }`